# borrow of possibly uninitialized variable for match operator

Tags: rust

I was designing a library that would transliterate given string into English from Ukrainian, so I decided to use 'match' operator for defining statement with check of multiple conditions. But I bumped into compiler error, which is typical to Rust, but fully impossible in my situation(at least I suppose so).

```
   --> src/lib.rs:188:21
    |
188 |  origin_mutated[i] = 'Y';
    |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of possibly-uninitialized `origin_mutated`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Here is full code of a library. Please bump my nose into a problem, if I'm not seeing something obvious(because I have suspicion that it may be a bug in compiler)

```
pub fn transliterate(mut origin: String) -> String {
    let counter: usize = origin.chars().count();
    let mut j: usize = 0;
    let mut i: usize = 0;
    let origin_vec: Vec<char> = origin.chars().collect();
    let mut origin_mutated: Vec<char>;
    if j <= counter{
        while j <= counter {
            match origin_vec[j] {
                'А' => {
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'A';
                    i+=1;
                    j+=1;
                    },
                'Б' => {
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'B';
                    j+=1;
                    i+=1;
                    },
                'В' => {
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'V';
                    i+=1;
                    j+=1;
                    },
                'Г' => {
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'H';
                    i+=1;
                    j+=1;
                    },
                'Ґ' => {
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'G';
                    i+=1;
                    j+=1;
                    },
                'Д' => {
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'D';
                    i+=1;
                    j+=1;
                    },
                'Е' => {
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'E';
                    i+=1;
                    j+=1;
                    },
                'Є' => {
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'Y';
                    i+=1;
                    j+=1;
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'e';
                    i+=1;
                    },
                'Ж' => {
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'Z';
                    i+=1;
                    j+=1;
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'h';
                    i+=1;
                    },
                'З' => {
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'Z';
                    i+=1;
                    j+=1;
                    },
                'И' => {
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'Y';
                    i+=1;
                    j+=1;
                    },
                'І' => {
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'I';
                    i+=1;
                    j+=1;
                    },
                'Ї' => {
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'Y';
                    i+=1;
                    j+=1;
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'i';
                    i+=1;
                    },
                'Й' => {
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'Y';
                    i+=1;
                    j+=1;
                    },
                'К' => {
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'K';
                    i+=1;
                    j+=1;
                    },
                'Л' => {
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'L';
                    i+=1;
                    j+=1;
                    },
                'М' => {
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'M';
                    i+=1;
                    j+=1;
                    },
                'Н' => {
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'N';
                    i+=1;
                    j+=1;
                    },
                'О' => {
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'O';
                    i==1;
                    j+=1;
                    },
                'П' => {
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'P';
                    i+=1;
                    j+=1;
                    },
                'Р' => {
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'R';
                    i==1;
                    j+=1;
                    },
                'С' => {
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'S';
                    i==1;
                    j+=1;
                    },
                'Т' => {
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'T';
                    i==1;
                    j+=1;
                    },
                'У' => {
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'U';
                    i+=1;
                    j+=1;
                    },
                'Ф' => {
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'F';
                    i==1;
                    j+=1;
                    },
                'Х' => {
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'K';
                    i+=1;
                    j==1;
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'h';
                    i+=1;
                    },
                'Ц' => {
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'T';
                    i+=1;
                    j+=1;
                    origin_mutated[i] = 's';
                    i+=1;
                    },
                'Ч' => {
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'C';
                    i+=1;
                    j+=1;
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'h';
                    i+=1;
                    },
                'Ш' => {
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'S';
                    i+=1;
                    j+=1;
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'h';
                    i+=1;
                    },
                'Щ' => {
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'S';
                    i+=1;
                    j==1;
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'h';
                    i+=1;
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'c';
                    i+=1;
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'h';
                    i+=1;
                    },
                'Ю' => {
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'Y';
                    i+=1;
                    j+=1;
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'u';
                    i+=1;
                    },
                'Я' => {
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'Y';
                    i+=1;
                    j+=1;
                    origin_mutated[i] = 'a';
                    i+=1;
                    },
                _ => {
                    j+=1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    else if j > counter{
        origin_mutated[i] = '\n'; 
    }
    else {
        origin = origin_mutated.into_iter().collect();
    }
    //origin = origin_mutated.into_iter().collect();
    (origin)
}
```

Comment: Scanning through by eye, there are a few `==`s that appear to have been substituted for `+=`s.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason for the error is that this line does NOT create a Vec:

```
let mut origin_mutated: Vec<char>;
```

It creates a variable which *could* hold a Vec, but doesn't yet, not even a zero-length one.  It's like saying

```
let a: i32;
```

It doesn't have a value.  You probably meant

```
let mut origin_mutated: Vec<char> = Vec::new();
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why your program doesn't compile, but even if it did compile, I think it'd probably panic when you try to index your `origin_mutated` vector. The reason is that your `origin_mutated` vec has a length of 0, so trying to index into it will panic according to [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#indexing).

You can't index into an element of your vector which doesn't exist yet. You'd need to use a method like `push()` or similar to grow your `Vec`.

But there's an even better way to do this with Rust: by iterating over the input `String` and `map`ping over its elements:

```rust
pub fn transliterate(origin: &str) -> String {
    origin.chars().map(transliterate_letter).collect()
}

fn transliterate_letter(letter: char) -> &'static str {
    match letter {
        'А' => "A",
        'Б' => "B",
        ...
        'Є' => "Ye",
        ...
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0bd2279b505acbe124697d194e169c57)

Comment: The code doesn't compile because the `origin_mutate` vec is never initialized with a value (and Rust disallows use of possibly uninitialized variables), so it doesn't even have a length `0`, but if it had been initialized with `Vec::new`, your answer would be completely correct.

Comment: @Frxstrem ah! I missed that it was only declared. However, in that case, I find it weird that the error doesn't occur on the line `origin_mutated[i] = 'A';` already.

Comment: Indeed it does compile by changing line 6 by `let mut origin_mutated: Vec<char> = vec![];`

Answer (score 0):

All stack variables in Rust are uninitialized until a value is explicitly assigned to them:

```rust
let mut origin_mutated: Vec<char>
```

Here, `origin_mutated` is not actually initialized as a vector. It it simply a placeholder for a vector that may or may not be initialized in the future.

Because Rust does not know if the variable was initialized, the compiler statically prevents you from reading it:

```rust
    |
188 |  origin_mutated[i] = 'Y';
    |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of possibly-uninitialized `origin_mutated`
```

The solution is to initialize `origin_mutated` as an empty vector:

```rust
let mut origin_mutated: Vec<char> = Vec::new()
```