# trying to implement selection sort in rust without using vectors

Tags: sorting, rust

I'm currently learning rust and implementing selection sort using it. I'm trying to implement it using arrays but not able to address the following error.

```
    fn selectionsort(arr: &[i32]) {
    let len = arr.len();
    let newarr: [i32; 5];
    let mut moved = 0;
    let mut max = 0;

    while moved < len {
        for x in 0..5 {
            if max < arr[x] {
                if !found(arr[x], &newarr) {
                    max = arr[x];
                }
            }
        }
        newarr[moved] = max;
        moved += 1;
    }
    println!("{:?}", newarr);
    //return &newarr;
}
fn found(x: i32, b: &[i32]) -> bool {
    for i in 0..b.len() {
        if x == b[i] {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

the error:

```
 error[E0381]: borrow of possibly-uninitialized variable: `newarr`
  --> src/main.rs:17:35
   |
17 |                 if !found(arr[x], &newarr) {
   |                                   ^^^^^^^ use of possibly-uninitialized `newarr`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

is it possible to implement the selection sort purely using arrays (like in C)?

edit: i'm comming from a C background and trying to implement the selection sort using purely primitives. before moving to generics. the suggested 'similar question' had solutions which were using vectors!

Comment: To solve that particular error, you just need to initialize the array:
e.g. `let newarr = [0; 5]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [borrow of possibly uninitialized variable for match operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60996303/borrow-of-possibly-uninitialized-variable-for-match-operator)

Comment: As @Prime_Aqasix indicated. You're trying to read from an uninitialised value. That's kosher in neither C nor Rust, though as you can see Rust will refuse to compile while in C it's UB.

Comment: This is not a selection sort though.

Comment: @Prime_Aqasix thanks! that prevents the compiler error. the program is now able to compile but there's a bug!. i'll update the code here when i've debugged it. thanks again.

Comment: @Masklinn you're right, there's a bug somewhere

Comment: @AntonA selection is an in-place sort, so if you have different input and output arrays it can't rightly be a selection sort.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Prime_Aqasix for the solution for the compiler error. as promised here's the final debugged code. it's still primitive and does not deal with repeating numbers ie: `[1, 2, 3, 3, 4]`. and no zero's.

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let a: [i32; 5] = [5, 4, 1, 3, 2];
    //let a: [i32; 5] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    selectionsort(&a);
}

fn selectionsort(arr: &[i32]) {
    //
    let len = arr.len();
    let mut newarr = [0; 5];
    let mut moved = 0;
    let mut max;

    while moved < len {
        max = find_max(&arr, &newarr, moved);
        newarr[moved] = max;
        moved += 1;
    }
    println!("{:?}", newarr);
    //return &newarr;
}
fn find_max(a: &[i32], b: &[i32], mut i: usize) -> i32 {
    if i != 0 {
        i -= 1;
    }
    let temp_m = b[i];
    let mut new_m = 0;
    for x in 0..a.len() {
        if temp_m == 0 || temp_m > a[x] {
            // ^this is already moved!
            if new_m < a[x] {
                new_m = a[x];
            }
        }
    }
    return new_m;
}
```